# Java user control desktop application

Tags: java

I am developing a user control desktop application for windows 8.1 using Java with netbeans

I want the app to lock the desktop by itself after 30minute time out

You can only use the computer unless you have entered your user name and password into the application
The app should take a complete control over the desktop, without entering username and password into the app you can't use the destop

I need guidelines and the classes and methods I will need to archive this task. I am a beginner in Java language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem in the following steps:
1- Search the internet about .DLL files for locking and unlocking your windows Desktop.

2- .DLL files are written in C or C++ language. 
3- You can invoke the .DLL file if and only if the java method from where you're invoking is declared as native(Also search the internet for this)

4- You must use the concept of multithreading(Sleep Timer like things) on the internet.
5- Because a sleep timer in java let you lock your desktop after some seconds or minutes and you can unlock your keyword by typing correct username and password into the fields.

6- Also search the internet about username authentication code in java.